# Changing tableview row height on the fly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a table view with 2 rows. initially setting the row heights accordingly. i then load another view controller which displays a list from which the user can select multiple items. these items will be drawn on the first row of the tableview as custom images. when the user clicks back, the selelction of items the user has selected are displayed, but i need to be able to adjust the height of row 0.

Comment: Are you calling reloadData on the original tableview after an item is selected?

Comment: i'll need to check that. i believe so, but will confirm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: i already use that code to set the initial row height, but it is not getting fired again when the user goes back to the table after selecting the items they want displaying.

Comment: Probably try `[tableview reloadData];` to refresh the tableview and apply the new height.

Answer (score 0):

on your TableListController header file declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath * expandedCellIndexPath;
```

then on the .m add

```
- (void)changeCellHeights:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.expandedCellIndexPath) {
        [self.yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: self.expandedCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    self.expandedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: self.expandedCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    DebugLog(@"");
    if (self.expandedCellIndexPath && indexPath.row == self.expandedCellIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == self.expandedCellIndexPath.section) {
        return 80;
    }
    return 56.0;
}
```

And finally don't forget to set your tableCell to Clip subviews (on your Xib, if you're using one)

All you need now is to call the changeCellHeights: method